# Python3 Dictionay KeyError: 264

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I've created a dictionary that contains something like following:

```
{ Location ID : [[latitude, Longitude], District Name]}
```

eg, `{ 13: [ [40.703278 , -74.017028], 'Manhattan' ]}`

Now i am trying to create and sort out a list of taxi order in another dictionary.

```
def trip_distribution(list):
    trips = {}
    for x in list:
        zone = zone_list[x[0]][1]
        if zone not in trips:
            trips[zone] = [x]
        else:
            trips[zone] = trips[zone] + [x]
        return trips
```

But when i ran the codes, it gave me an error that i cannot explain:
  `File "test_function.py", line 144, in trip_distribution
    zone = zone_list[x[0]][1]
KeyError: 264`

Anybody knows what is going on?

Comment: No, we don't, because you haven't showed us what `zone_list` is.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: "Key error: 264" means that you tried to access the record for key 264, but there was no such record in the dict.  If you want specific help, you need to provide the code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeyError: 264 means that it cannot find a key in the dictionary that matches 264.

it is hard to tell where it is going wrong because we don't know what is in zone_list and list. But try using zone = zone_list[x][1]

Comment: Sure it does, but this doesn't really answer the question. Actually, this question cannot be answered without more info from Op.

Comment: Oh, I that is true. My dictionary has keys up to 263.. I will work on that, thanks so much